# Compute the Wronskian and Simplify

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

> **a)** Compute the **Wronskian** and simplify
>
> \begin{align} y_1 = t^2 + 1\\ y_2 = 3t^2 + k \end{align}

So I computed the Wronskian and got: 
\begin{align}6t-2kt \Longleftrightarrow t(6-2k).
\end{align}

> **b)** For what values of $k$ are the two functions **linearly independent**?

So I know that the functions are linearly independent because I took the Wronskian and didn't get $0$. I'm not sure though for what values of $k$.. Would it be all values of $k$ as long as $k$ is not $3$ because $6t-6t = 0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wronskian is
\begin{align}
W\left[y_1,\cdots y_n\right]\left(x\right):=\det\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_n\\
y'_1 & y'_2 & \cdots & y'_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
y^{\left(n-1\right)}_1 & y^{\left(n-1\right)}_2 & \cdots & y^{\left(n-1\right)}_n
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
and using your functions we have
\begin{align}
y_1=t^2+1,\\y_2=3t^2+k,
\end{align}
which gives us
\begin{align}
W\left[y_1,y_2\right]\left(t\right)&=\det\begin{bmatrix}
t^2+1 & 3t^2+k\\
2t & 6t
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=6t\left(t^2+1\right)-\left(3t^2+k\right)2t\\
&=6t^3+6t-\left(6t^3+2tk\right)\\
&=6t-2tk,
\end{align}
and therefore the linear independence of these two functions is dependent upon $k\neq 3$, otherwise these two solutions would not be linearly independent.